# Why my Arduino calculates from 0 to 1 billion faster than my MacBook air?

Tags: c++, arduino

Here's my MacBook Air result in c++, execution time: 2.692 seconds

[image]

Here is my Arduino code. It gets the time in microseconds before the 'for' and after it.
The difference is 732 microseconds which is 0.000732 seconds

[image]

Comment: Well your the c++ code you run is not the only process that is running.

Comment: How does `time = micros()` work? Shouldn't you be storing the first one, and then subtracting the second one from the first?  Otherwise, it's just some random number you're reading there.  How long did it feel like it took to run on the Arduino?  One thousand one, one thousand two...

Comment: It reads the microsseconds that passed since the arduino were turned on, so 792-60 is the time that passed between the code

Comment: Wild guess: the difference is constant and some initialization is taking the toll on the C++ version. Please try doubling or tripling the loop length and see if the difference stays constant or diminishes. (if the C++ code is running faster, it will diminish and eventually eat up the initialization gap)

Comment: Are you certain that the `for` loop in the arduino code isn't being optimized away?

Comment: Yeah, @Lucas, the Macbook version almost certainly has a long spinup time, relative to the Arduino version.  You should be measuring *only the loops* in both versions, not the entire program.  Otherwise, it's not apples and apples.

Comment: I changed the number to 4.000.000.000 and it took 11.521 seconds, so I think the problem is more than 'code initialization'

Comment: Just out of curiosity, can you try compiling the PC version in release mode?

Comment: There is some overhead involved in macbook for starting the process, which may be more then the bootloader for the arduino.  This could be a big part of the 2 seconds, even if the program execution is extremely fast.  It may be the load time before the program starts executing.

Comment: Yeah but I changed the number to 4.000.000.000 and it took 11.521 seconds, a pretty good difference for the problem being just the code execution from the c++ libraries, I think

Comment: Are you running other programs on your macbook?  It could be executing other items when you are running as well. Is the 11.521 seconds the wall clock time to execute or the amount of processor time to execute?

Comment: The entire program runned into 11.521 seconds

Answer (score 13):

Lets look at how MSVC compiles your code in debug mode, as you seem to be compiling it...

```
unsigned int max = 1000000000L;
    011643BE  mov         dword ptr [max],3B9ACA00h  
for (unsigned int i=0; i<max; i++)
    011643C5  mov         dword ptr [ebp-14h],0  
    011643CC  jmp         main+37h (011643D7h)  
    011643CE  mov         eax,dword ptr [ebp-14h]  
    011643D1  add         eax,1  
    011643D4  mov         dword ptr [ebp-14h],eax  
    011643D7  mov         eax,dword ptr [ebp-14h]  
    011643DA  cmp         eax,dword ptr [max]  
for (unsigned int i=0; i<max; i++)
    011643DD  jae         main+4Eh (011643EEh)  
{
    n++;
    011643DF  mov         eax,dword ptr ds:[0116F218h]  
    011643E4  add         eax,1  
    011643E7  mov         dword ptr ds:[0116F218h],eax  
}
011643EC  jmp         main+2Eh (011643CEh)
```

Ok, now lets see that in release mode...

```
unsigned int max = 1000000000L;
for (unsigned int i=0; i<max; i++)
    00FC1270  mov         eax,dword ptr ds:[00FC4430h]  
{
    n++;
}
std::cout << n;
    00FC1275  mov         ecx,dword ptr ds:[0FC3030h]  
    00FC127B  add         eax,3B9ACA00h  
    00FC1280  push        eax  
    00FC1281  mov         dword ptr ds:[00FC4430h],eax  
    00FC1286  call        dword ptr ds:[0FC3038h]
```

Notice the difference? The release mode has completely **optimized out the loop**.

Ok, now lets switch gears and see how Arduino does this. Get ready for some AVR asm...

```
for(i=0; i<1000000000; i++)
{
 n++;
}
Serial.println(n);
    d8: c8 01           movw    r24, r16
    da: 40 e0           ldi r20, 0x00   ; 0
    dc: 5a ec           ldi r21, 0xCA   ; 202
    de: 6a e9           ldi r22, 0x9A   ; 154
    e0: 7b e3           ldi r23, 0x3B   ; 59
    e2: 2a e0           ldi r18, 0x0A   ; 10
    e4: 30 e0           ldi r19, 0x00   ; 0
    e6: 0e 94 c4 04     call    0x988   ; 0x988 <_ZN5Print7printlnEli>
```

Whoa! It optimized the loop out as well! The compiler is a smart little bugger, innit?!?!

...And when you think about it, isn't .0007 seconds a little bit quick to perform that long of a loop? That's only enough time for about 43 clock cycles -- barely enough to call `Serial.println()`.

Answer (score 12):

Firstly, the code you wrote is very simplistic. The result of compilation for such code will vary wildly depending on the compiler and compiler settings. A properly configured optimizing compiler will typically compile it into a plain assignment of the final value of `n` without any cycles. Or it can even eliminate `n` entirely. In which case what your are really measuring is just "emptiness": a start up and termination time for a program that does [almost] nothing.

Secondly, the measuring methods you are using appear to be completely different between the two versions of the code. In the first case you appear to be using something at the system level, meaning that it probably includes various start up and wrap up times into the final tally. In the second case you embedded the measurements into the actual code, making sure that only the cycle is measured (which, again, is probably eliminated by the compiler).

In other words, you are using inconsistent methods to time something that probably does not even exist. The results you obtained bear very little relevance to the performance of the code or, more likely, make no relevant sense at all.

Comment: You're rigth, I'm gonna try with the same measurement method in the two codes, but look: I changed the number to 4.000.000.000 and it took 11.521 seconds to run. Let's say 2 seconds are just for initialating the libraries. Would be so much difference, don't you think? Thanks! :)

Comment: @Lucas Zanella: If the code on some platform is linearly sensitive to the number of iterations, it means that the cycle was not eliminated. Either the compiler was not smart enough, or the compilation settings prevented optimizations. Are you sure the compiler on the other platform behaved in the same way? Is the other platform also linearly sensitive to the number of iterations?

Comment: I'm gonna try this. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The relevant technical explanation has been given by AndreyT, but here is a quick and dirty estimate that helps looking in the right direction:

Suppose the Arduino actually managed 1 billion (1e9) increments in roughly a millisecond (730 microseconds), and disregard the extra increment and check for the loop counter as well as the jump instruction, that would mean that the Arduino can process increments at a frequency of at least 1e12 Hz, which is 1000 GHz (note that this is an estimate for the frequency of processed increment instructions, which is not necesserily equivalent to 'CPU frequency' but a fairly okay estimator in the absence of any other information). Unlikely. It is therefore safe to assume that your arduino compiler simply eliminated the entire loop.

(The same estimate for your MacBook gives a frequency of at least (1e9/2.7) Hz, so roughly 370Mhz of increments - factoring in OS overhead an the fact that the loop needs the extra increment, the jump and the comparison, this works out fairly close to your processor freq, so I would guess that your compiler for the Mac program actually keeps the loop.)